# narrow-band and wide-band

Tags: digital-communications

My question concerns the definition of a narrow-band signal and a wide-band signal. To determine the nature of the signal, the following relation is used: $\alpha=\frac{B}{f_c}$ where $B$ is the signal bandwidth and $f_c$ the carrier frequency.

If $\alpha<1$, the signal is narrow-band or wide-band otherwise.

Are you agree with this definition?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with such a definition. Commercial waveforms like those of 3G UMTS, 4G LTE, and 5G NR use multiple-MHz $B$ at GHz $f_c$ carriers are all branded "wideband" and "broadband". Typically a signal is called narrowband when $\alpha \ll 1$.

Answer (score 4):

I've never thought of narrowband vs wideband in terms of the carrier frequency. When somebody says narrowband to me it means that the channel is flat. In communications terminology it is the systems bandwidth does not exceed the channel's coherence bandwidth, where the coherence bandwidth is the bandwidth over which the channel can be thought of as flat. Wideband means the system bandwidth exceeds the coherence bandwidth and so the channel variation comes into play.

Narrowband $\leftrightarrow$ flat channel, relatively simpler system modeling

Wideband $\leftrightarrow$ varying channel, relatively more complex system modeling